# Retornando valor nulo ao criar tabela no WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Estou criando um Plugin e preciso que ao ativar ele crie a tabela referente na DB, porém o dbDelta está retornando que a tabela foi criada, mas ao verificar utilizando `$wpdb->get_var` retorna um valor nulo. Ou seja, a tabela não está realmente sendo criada na DB, já verifiquei através do PHPMyAdmin.

Qual deve ser o problema na seguinte função?

```
function main(){
    global $wpdb;

    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $leads = $prefix . 'leads';

    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE $leads") != $leads):
        $query = 
            "CREATE TABLE $leads (
                id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                nome varchar(64) NULL, 
                email varchar(64) NULL, 
                telefone varchar(15) NULL, 
                celular varchar(15) NULL, 
                mensagem tinytext NULL
            );";

        // REFERENCE TO upgrade.php FILE
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        $var = dbDelta($query);
        var_dump($var); // RETORNA = array(1) { ["ic_leads"]=> string(22) "Created table ic_leads" }
    endif;

    var_dump($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE $leads")); // RETORNA = NULL
}
```

Comment: E o código da função `dbDelta()` ?

Comment: dbDelta() é uma função padrão do Wordpress, o ";" no final da string da $query não é problema, é de sintase padrão SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei a estrutura da sua tabela direto no banco e retornou o seguinte erro:

> Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one
>   auto column and it must be defined as a key

Ou seja é necessario definir a chave primária dessa tabela e ela deve ser o campo       `auto increment`, no caso `id`.

deixe a estrutura da sua tabela assim:

```sql
CREATE TABLE $leads (
                id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                nome varchar(64) NULL, 
                email varchar(64) NULL, 
                telefone varchar(15) NULL, 
                celular varchar(15) NULL, 
                mensagem tinytext NULL,
                primary key(id)
            );
```

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado!